# Failed request between pods

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I have a cluster on EKS with some APIs running on it, this is the yaml file used to deploy them:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: <api-name>
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: <api-name>
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: <container-port>
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <api-name>
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <api-name>
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <api-name>
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: <api-name>
        image: <ecr-image-url>
        ports:
        - containerPort: <container-port>
          name: <api-name>
        env:
          - name: ENVIRONMENT
            value: <environment>
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <api-name>
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <app-name>.<dns>
    http:
      paths:
      -  backend:
          serviceName: <api-name>
          servicePort: 80
```

The routing works perfectly ok (Network Load Balancer created by nginx-ingress), but when I try to make a request from one pod to another, I receive a:

```
[2020-08-14 11:49:42,214] ERROR in app: Exception on /services [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1948, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2242, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/app/app/views/__init__.py", line 12, in before_rest_callback
    validate_request(token)
  File "/app/app/utils.py", line 29, in validate_request
    response = httpx.post(url, headers=headers, timeout=60)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_api.py", line 269, in post
    return request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_api.py", line 86, in request
    return client.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 640, in request
    return self.send(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 670, in send
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 699, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 736, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_single_request(request, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 759, in _send_single_request
    (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_exceptions.py", line 359, in map_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message, **kwargs) from None  # type: ignore
httpx._exceptions.ReadError: Server disconnected while attempting read
```

I can get no connection between pods. The request doesn't reach the other application, running on the same cluster, same node. Nginx Ingress was installed following the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws).

Any clues about what might be causing this? I discarded anything related to the deployment (API or gunicorn in this case). It seems to be something related to the cluster and/or nginx-ingress. Tried searching about it and found stuff related to "idle timeout", but that's not applicable to Network Load Balancers.

Comment: Could you provide list of your services and pods? How you are trying to connect between pods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved using `http://<app-name>` (app-name being the service name). Reference: [How to implement Kubernetes POD to POD Communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949522/how-to-implement-kubernetes-pod-to-pod-communication#answer-54949627)